# About UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(:::) method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an image and the size is 2347kb after using the `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(:::)` method. Use photos to view the size probably 737kb. Why? I really don't know. Who can tell me?

Code:

```
NSData * data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1);
CGFloat length = [data length]/1024.0; // 2347 kb
self.showLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0fKB",length];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.scalePhoto, self,@selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), NULL);

//result
- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
 {
    NSData * data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1);
    CGFloat length = [data length]/1024.0; // 2347 kb
    NSLog(@"image = %@, error = %@, contextInfo = %@", image, error, contextInfo);
    if (error) {
        [Tools acquirePhotoAuth:^(BOOL grant) {
            if (!grant) {
                //setting
            }
            else{
               //error
            }

        }];
    }
    else{
        //success
    }
 }
```

Why in desktop it shows size of 737kb?

Comment: `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` is using it's own way to convert the `UIImage` into a file. Don't assume it uses `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1)`.

Comment: what should I do , I want the same size of it